# Winui 3: How to add custom controls to a collection property in xaml code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winui-3

I have two custom controls:

- **CustomControl1**

```
  public sealed class CustomControl1 : Control
    {

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(DetailsList.Items), typeof(ObservableCollection<CustomControl2>), typeof(CustomControl1),
           PropertyMetadata.Create(new CreateDefaultValueCallback(() =>
           {
               return new ObservableCollection<CustomControl2>();
           }))


            );


        public ObservableCollection<CustomControl2> Items
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<CustomControl2>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
      
        }



        public CustomControl1()
        {
            SetValue(ItemsProperty, new ObservableCollection<CustomControl2>());
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);

           
        }

      
    }
```

```
  <Style TargetType="local2:CustomControl1" >

        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local2:CustomControl1">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Items}"></ItemsControl>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

- **CustomControl2**

```
   public sealed class CustomControl2 : Control
    {
        public CustomControl2()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl2);
        }
    }
```

```
<Style TargetType="local2:CustomControl2" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local2:CustomControl2">
                    <Border
                        Height="30"
                        Background="Red"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I want to add some  **CustomControl2** items to the **CustomControl1.Items** collection property from Xaml code:

```
  <myControls:CustomControl1>
                    <myControls:CustomControl1.Items>

                        <myControls:CustomControl2></myControls:CustomControl2>
                        <myControls:CustomControl2></myControls:CustomControl2>
                        <myControls:CustomControl2></myControls:CustomControl2>
                      
                    </myControls:CustomControl1.Items>
                </myControls:CustomControl1>
```

When I compile the code works, but when I add a new item in debug mode get me an error:

> Error XHR0015 CustomControl2 could not be added to ObservableCollection`1. Item not found.

What did I do wrong in the code?
What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, there are a few lines that I don't understand in your code. For example, the way you implement the **Items** dependency property and the value **DetailList**.

So, since I couldn't reproduce your issue, I'm just going to share a sample code that works for me. It'll add a new `CustomControl2` to the `Items` when the button is clicked.

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3App2">

    <Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button x:Name="ButtonControl" />
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Items}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="local:CustomControl2">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl2">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Name}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**CustomControl1.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WinUI3App2;

[TemplatePart(Name = nameof(ButtonControl), Type = typeof(Button))]
public sealed class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (this.ButtonControl is not null)
        {
            this.ButtonControl.Click -= ButtonControl_Click;
        }

        if (GetTemplateChild(nameof(this.ButtonControl)) is Button button)
        {
            this.ButtonControl = button;
            this.ButtonControl.Click += ButtonControl_Click;
        }
    }

    private void ButtonControl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Items.Add(new CustomControl2() { Name = "New Item" });
    }

    private Button? ButtonControl { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomControl2> Items
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<CustomControl2>)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Items),
        typeof(ObservableCollection<CustomControl2>),
        typeof(CustomControl1),
        new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<CustomControl2>()));
}
```

**CustomControl2.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WinUI3App2;

public sealed class CustomControl2 : Control
{
    public CustomControl2()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl2);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3App2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3App2"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <local:CustomControl1>
            <local:CustomControl1.Items>
                <local:CustomControl2 x:Name="CustomControl2A"/>
                <local:CustomControl2 x:Name="CustomControl2B"/>
                <local:CustomControl2 x:Name="CustomControl2C"/>
            </local:CustomControl1.Items>
        </local:CustomControl1>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```